# Specific Customer Offer in Broadleaf Commerce

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf, broadleaf-commerce

We are using Broadleaf Commerce Frameworks to developer our E-Commerce Application. Can anybody tell me How can I apply an offer to a Specific Customer ?

```
I have tried that one but, not working for the Specific Customer. It is becoming common for all....

Please tell me if you have any Idea ....


Thanking you
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Broadleaf 3.0+ (we recommend 3.1.0-GA or 3.0.9-GA), you can add a rule to target the specific customer. If you go in the admin to Catalog -> Offers, create or edit an offer and then scroll down to 'Qualification Criteria'.

[image]